# Can we manage session in Mulesoft?

Tags: java, mule, mule-studio

I created an application using mule. For every event, webhook make calls to my mule flow. I have to store the information from every call and use that information to make a payload. But I cannot make it because the previous call information is replaced by new call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, 
you can do it with `objectStore` to store and retrieve information later.
[Object Store ref:](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/mule-object-stores)

Answer (score 0):

yes we can maintain the session by using the session variables or by using the object store we can store and we can retrieve when we want.